# How to return child enity along with its parent entity details in springboot

Tags: java, spring-boot, java-stream

I want to get Loans details along with each loan Parent details, but i am geting only Child details not parent details.

Loan is the child entity, and User is the Parent Entity

```
Pageable pageable = PageRequest.of(page, size);
Page<Loan> loanPage= this.loanRepo.findByStaffIdAndDateBetween(staffId, startDate, endDate, pageable);

List<Loan> modifiedLoans = loanPage.stream().map(ele-> {
ele.setUser(ele.getUser); 
                    return ele; }).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

ParentEntyity

```
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Data
@Entity
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.IntSequenceGenerator.class, property = "@id")
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private Long mobile;
    private String name;
    private String email;

    @ToString.Exclude
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "user", orphanRemoval = true)
    @JsonIgnore
    private List<Loan> loan = new ArrayList<>();

}
```

child Enity

```
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Data
@Entity
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.IntSequenceGenerator.class, property = "@id")
public class Loan {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;    
    private String status;  

    @ToString.Exclude
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    @JsonIgnore
    private User user;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `@JsonManagedReference` `@JsonBackReference` to handle bidirectional relationships in Jackson here. If you are not familiar with this find details [here](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-bidirectional-relationships-and-infinite-recursion)

Replace parentEntity like this

```
    @JsonManagedReference
    @ToString.Exclude
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "user", orphanRemoval = true)
    @JsonIgnore
    private List<Loan> loan = new ArrayList<>();
```

and child entity like this

```
    @JsonBackReference
    @ToString.Exclude
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    @JsonIgnore
    private User user;
```